# Calculating $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{tan^4(2x)}{4x^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I’m trying to solve the following limit
$$\lim_{x\to0}  \frac{\tan^4(2x)}{4x^4}$$ I have made this process.
$$\lim_{x\to0}  \frac{\frac{1}{2}\tan^4(2x)}{\frac{1}{2}4x^4}$$ then I use the identity  $$ \lim_{x\to 0}  \frac{\tan(x)}{x}=1$$ and the answer I get is 1, but the answer in the book is 4, so I don’t know what to do to get that answer

Answer (score 3):

If we set $y=2x$ this is
$$\lim_{y\to0}4\frac{\tan^4y}{y^4}=4\lim_{y\to0}\left(
\frac{\tan y}{y}\right)^4.$$

Comment: If $y=2x$ then what is $4/y^4$?

Answer (score 1):

write it as
$$\frac{(\tan(2x))^4}{(2x)^4}\cdot \frac{16}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan^4(2x)}{2^{2}x^4}=2^{2}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan^4(2x)}{2^{4}x^4}=4.$$